# Pointer Manipulation in C

Tags: c, pointers

Hey everybody ! I am a beginner programmer and need some help with pointers. This is what I am trying to do: I have two pointer arguments to a function(caller), say arg1 and arg2. Now I want to manipulate these pointers inside some other function, say func,  such that change reflects in the caller from where the func was called. However right now the change I make in the function gets undone in the calling function. Here is the source code:

```
func(node* arg1, node* argv2)
{
  node* point3 = (struct node*) malloc(struct node);
  arg2 = arg1;
  arg 1  = point3;
}

caller(node* argv1, node* argv2)
{
  func(arg1, arg2);
}
```

Now I know that this can be done using pass by reference technique. But for that func becomes `func(node** arg, node** arg2)` and I dont want to get into double pointers. I was thinking more on the lines of how an array when manipulated or changed in a function changes for all the functions in the program. Please help me out !

Comment: Just an FYI: In strict C you're not really supposed to cast the result of `malloc`. Also, you should be passing in `sizeof(struct node)` instead of the type. I'm surprised this even compiles, honestly.

Comment: You are right. I used sizeof in the original code. Forgot to write it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do it:
1) Swap pointers, for this you need to use double pointers(`**`)

```
func(node** arg1, node** arg2)
{
  node* tmp = *arg2;
  *arg2 = *arg1;
  *arg1  = tmp;
}
```

2) Swap content, I think you can do it like this:

```
func(node* arg1, node* arg2)
{
  node* tmp = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  node* clean = tmp; 
  *tmp = *arg2;
  *arg2 = *arg1;
  *arg1  = *tmp;
  free(clean);
}
```

Method #1 is more efficient since it will swap pointers instead of whole struct. And as someone mentioned, you should use `sizeof()` inside malloc.

Comment: -1 for case 2 which leaks memory and is dangerously confusing

Comment: True, it was leaking memory. I fixed it now.

Comment: You still shouldn't allocate that on heap if you just need it locally.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the pointers themselves, you need to pass pointer to pointer.
Therefore `func(node** arg1, node** arg2)` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the double pointer is really the right way to do it.  But if you find that confusing, you could pass an array of two pointers to the function instead.  Then the contents of the array would be modified upon return.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, using pointers to pointers in this case is how it's done in C. There is however a possibility to avoid this: use macros....

```
#define func(arg1, argv2) do { node * point3 = malloc(); /* etc ... */ } while(0)
```

But your code is not gonna be more beautiful by doing to that. Don't be tempted by the dark side of C.